# JSONata: Passing a location instead of timezone to $now()

Tags: date, datetime, time, timezone, jsonata

I work with clients in different time zones, and it's not feasible for me to adapt manually twice a year to accomodate daylight savings. I'm looking for a native JSONata solution that would allow me to set a time based on the location (instead of the timezone or timezone offset) to keep my output accurate year-round.

I can give out the local time for Germany during summer using below query, but this forces me to update to '+0100' in winter.
`$fromMillis($millis(), '[H01]:[m01]', '+0200')`

I am looking for something like:
`$fromMillis($millis(), '[H01]:[m01]', 'Europe/Berlin')`

From the official documentation (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-dateTime) it looks technically possible but I can't for the life of me figure out the correct syntax. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in this GitHub issue (https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/347), JSONata does not expose locale settings. The issue suggests using an external library (jsonata-moment) for this.

Assuming you're working is a JavaScript environment, you can use Date.getTimezoneOffset() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) to compute the offset before assembling your JSONata expression.

The documentation states that "In a region that annually shifts in and out of Daylight Saving Time (DST), as date varies, the number of minutes returned by calling getTimezoneOffset() can be non-uniform".

If you do not have access to the JSONata engine, you can use the following JSONata snippet that detects whether daylight savings time is active in central Europe (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerzeit#Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische_Sommerzeit):

```
/* test cases */
["2023-01", "2023-03-31", "2023-10-01", "2023-12"].$toMillis($).(

    /* reduce function to find "sunday" in an array */
    $sunday := function($a, $v, $i) { $v = "sunday" ? $i : $a};

    /* parse date */
    $year := $number($fromMillis($, "[Y]"));
    $month := $number($fromMillis($, "[M]"));
    $day := $number($fromMillis($, "[D]"));
    $weekday := $fromMillis($, "[F]");

    /* daylight savings changes on the last sunday on mar / oct */
    /* using the current year, find these dates */ 
    $mar := $year & "-03-" & (25+$reduce([25,26,27,28,29,30,31].$toMillis($year & "-03-" & $).$fromMillis($, '[F]'), $sunday));
    $oct := $year & "-10-" & (25+$reduce([25,26,27,28,29,30,31].$toMillis($year & "-10-" & $).$fromMillis($, '[F]'), $sunday));

    {
        "year": $year,
        "month": $month,
        "day": $day,
        "weekday": $weekday,
        "mar": $mar,
        "oct": $oct,
        "summer": $toMillis($mar) < $ and $ < $toMillis($oct)
    }
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited to using JSONata on an isolated UI with no option to add on JS functionality. But thanks a lot for confirming it's not just me!

Comment: You could implement the rule when daylight savings is active (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerzeit#Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische_Sommerzeit) using JSONata.

Comment: I think I'll try that - bit cumbersome for more than one country / time zone but at least there's a concrete rule around the exact time of change each year. Thanks a lot for the idea and the code example!